# Get a defined image-transform's width and height in front-end template

Tags: image-transforms

Is it possible to retrieve a control panel defined imagetransform’s dimensions in a front-end template without having to retrieve an asset? Because when there is no asset provided, I can't seem to find a (dynamic) way to get the width and height of the transform in order to calculate dimensions for a placeholder div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft 3 you can call it like this:

```
{% set transformDimensions = craft.app.assetTransforms.getTransformByHandle('contentWidth') %}
```

width: `{{ transformDimensions.width }}`
height: `{{ transformDimensions.height }}`
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Craft does not provide the assetTransformService in the craft.variable but you can include it by yourself.
Create a function in your PluginVariable.php that does

```
public function getTransformationByHandle($handle){
    return craft()->assetTransforms->getTransformByHandle($handle);
}
```

and in your twig template
`{% set transformation = craft.pluginHandle.getTransformationByHandle('yourHandle') %}`

Edit: if you don't have a custom plugin then visit this page [Pluginfactory](https://pluginfactory.io/) fill out the inputs and select the lightswitch for "variable" paste my function into the `/variables/pluginHandleVariable.php` file and create a folder with the same name as your pluginhandle (the one you inserted in the input at the page) in `/app/plugins/` then go to the control panel, install the plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply but this just solved my problem! Thank you very much!