# Use Imager plugin with AssetTransforms defined in admin panel

Tags: assets, image-transforms, plugin-imager

I'm trying to use the Imager plugin with some asset transforms that I've defined in the admin panel.  Passing the name of the transform is just tossing an error at me.  Is there a way to do this, or do I need to define the transforms inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem. You can do it by creating a custom plugin that returns image transform info. Look here => [Get a defined image-transform's width and height in front-end template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22517/get-a-defined-image-transforms-width-and-height-in-front-end-template)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to define your transforms inline - Imager doesn't support named (i.e. CP-/admin-defined) transforms.